# I loose the swap every time I restart my Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, swap, ubuntu-17.04

Here is how I set the swap:

```
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1MB count="1000"
sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

Every time I reboot/restart the swap is gone.

The command `free` gives me zeros for swap. But the file `/var/swap.1` is still there.

`swap.1` file details:

`-rw-r--r--  1 root root   989000000 Aug  9 20:55 swap.1`

The number **989000000** seems a bit big...

How can I make it persistent?

lsb_release -a

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

Comment: Is the file disappearing after reboot? Or are you asking for the format of the /etc/fstab line?

Comment: The /var/swap.1 file is still there. But when I run `free` it's all zeros for swap.

Comment: `The number 989000000 seems a bit big` - Why do you think that?  It seems a bit small to me given the commands you posted should be creating a file that is 1000*1MB (1048576000 bytes).

Comment: Hrm, apparently 1MB in dd is `10^6` not the  `2**20` I was expecting.  Stupid SI vs binary prefixes.

Comment: @Zoredache, still too small, though: 1000 1MB chunks shouldn't be less than 1 000 000 000 bytes no matter which version of "M" you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the system to automatically use the swap file as swap space on boot, it needs an entry in `/etc/fstab` similar to:

```
/var/swap.1 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Comment: **989000000** is this normal?

Comment: That is the size of the file in bytes.